# galleriffic not working right

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, image-gallery

Guys,
I'm trying to work with galleriffic and rails 3, but it's not working correctly.It only makes the right effect with the thumbs, but with the main image it not works. When I click in the "next photo" button, the main image remains the same. I don't know what is going wrong, so here it is the code of gallery_detail.html.erb:

Update: sorry, I putted the wrong code. here it is the right one:
https://gist.github.com/909708

Comment: sorry Groovetrain, it was purposeless.

Comment: Ok, I'D like to help with this, but the gist that you've given is not formatted very well, and you've only given js, and far too much (only need the pertinent code) not any html that it's doing anything with. If you could pare it down and paste it into your question that would help.

Comment: This is what I was talking about in my first comment.  I spent a lot of time on my answer, and you haven't even commented on my answer or told me if I helped you out at all :(  Oh well.  I'll treat it as a burnt offering

Comment: How this ended up? was the answer the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you look at your actual outputted html it would help.  It looks like you are not correctly starting and ending your `<li>` tags.  Specifically this block of code:

```
<ul class="thumbs noscript">
  <% @gallery_photos.each do |g| %>
    <% if g.geometry == 'vertical' %>
      <li> <img src = "<%= g.photo.url("small") %>" style="height:65px;"/>
    <% else %>
      <img src="<%= g.photo.url("small") %>" style="height:65px; width:80px;"/></li></a>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  </li>
</ul>
```

What's up with the ending `</li>`, and that stray `</a>`?  Also, you'll notice that `li`'s aren't created in each circumstance.  And I think that these are supposed to be links (`a`'s) to something.  I'd definitely start there; I think the problem is most likely in this block of code.